# What is the significance of craft.app.request.segments|last == _self

Tags: templating

While reading this blog article about [RSS templating](http://craftsnippets.com/articles/rss-feed-template-component-for-craft-cms), I came across the following twig code

```
if craft.app.request.segments|last == _self
```

I understand that the above command, in general, yields URL components as an array. But I don't understand under what scenario is the above condition true. What does `_self` mean in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Twig 2, `_self` seems to reference the name of the current template file.

Running `{{ dump(_self) }}` from the file `/templates/test/index.twig` would return the string `test/index`.

So what it's being used for in this example...

```
{% if craft.app.request.segments|last == _self %}
```

... is to test wether the last segment in the URL matches the template file. Or "is this template being loaded directly from the file-based routing or is it being included from another template?"

I would point out tho, this only matches the last segment. It assumes your `feed.rss` file it in the root templates directory. A more flexible approach would be to math the entire URI path.

```
{% if craft.app.request.pathInfo == _self %}
```

Later `_self` is used to generate a link with `{{ url(_self) }}`. This is the same as `{{ url('feed.rss') }}` but would update if you changed the file name (e.g. news.rss).

The whole point of that conditional is to replace the `{% include 'feed.rss' %}` with a `<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" href="{{ url('feed.rss') }}">`. Which seems a little complicated. After all, it provoked this Stack Exchange question. ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. everything is clear now :)